# How to write custom sort logic on sort column event in ng2-smart-table

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I'm looking to hook-up sort events performed on ng2-smart-table. Followed https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation, I see bunch of events that are exposed like rowSelect, mouseover  etc but I don't see sort events published/emitted by the library. I'm thinking of changing Ng2SmartTableComponent and emit an event when (sort) is called internally. May I know if anyone did it already or is there a hack I can rely upon.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the sort in ng2-smart-table is shown on GitHub ([link to code](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/943ce55125a003c1ee1f61a0bc92ad728b46ee34/src/ng2-smart-table/lib/data-source/local/local.sorter.ts)).

If you want to change the compare-Function (as used by default) you can add your own custom function in your ng2-smart-table-configuration:

```
columns: {
    group_name: {
        title: 'Groupname',
        compareFunction(direction: any, a: any, b: any) => {
           //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an event to sort my data remotely and I have found a solution. Also I have some logic for page change event (remote paging). Here is what works for me.

ts

```
source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

ngOnInit() {
  this.source.onChanged().subscribe((change) => {
    if (change.action === 'sort') {
      this.sortingChange(change.sort);
    }
    else if (change.action === 'page') {
      this.pageChange(change.paging.page);
    }
  });
}
```

html

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source"></ng2-smart-table>
```

This solution won't replace custom logic but it might help you solve your problem.